# File Manager Recs!

Tags: nautilus, software-recommendation, filemanager

I'm new but slowly getting situated to Linux/Ubuntu and I'm finding Nautilus to be pretty but lacking. I was wondering if you guys could recommend a file manager that:

1. Can show tree view
2. Has individual folder options. Like, for my photos folder I want to see extra large thumbnails rather than icons, with list view everywhere else.
3. Option to see the actual address/path, rather than the path address set as default in Nautilus.
4. Modern-looking. No win98 GUIs please!

Basically ... something that'll mimic Windows 10 lol ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I looked at that one! It looks too much like windows 98 and unfortunately I couldn't find a way to make it have different folder options. It could very well be that I missed a setting somewhere. Regardless - thanks for your reply.

Comment: What you mean by "that one"? The question has 6 answers. My opinion: If you generally like Nautilus, but want more features, try Nemo.

Comment: XFE* Imma try Nemo